# How to set up Analytics Goal from Adwords data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I set up a dynamic Google Forwarding number in Adwords on a website to track calls.

How the heck can I pull this data into Google Analytics and set it up as a Goal?? I am also using Tag Manager. But so far, I haven't been able to come up with any workaround to accomplish this.

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you post code or screenshots of what you have already tried, and also the errors you are getting?

Comment: Well, Adwords gives a code snippet which you can either put on your website or (in my case), I added it as a Tag in Google Tag Manager like so: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PsMHK4uSMhYTMzeWlvc0FtTXM/view?usp=sharing

This does not require a trigger or anything. Yet it doesn't allow me any other settings to where I can somehow set it up as an Event either, in order for me to be able to track it as a Goal in Analytics....